# cloudera Oozie sqoop2 job hangs running forever Heart beat Heart beat

Tags: sqoop, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to run two sqoop jobs in parallel using oozie. But two jobs are stuck after 95 % , other two are in accepted state.I have also increased yarn resource maximum memory . also added

```
<name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
<value>50 </value> 
 in mapred-site.xml , but nothing helped. please help.

Yarn Cluster Metrix:
Apps Submitted          4
Apps Pending            2
Apps Running            2
Apps Completed          0
Containers Running      4
Memory Used             10GB
Memory Total            32GB
Memory Reserved         0B
VCores Used             4
VCores Total            24
VCores Reserved         0
Active Nodes            4
Decommissioned Nodes    0
Lost Nodes              0
Unhealthy Nodes         0
Rebooted Nodes          0
----------
Sysout Log 
========================================================================
3175 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.SqoopTool  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
  3198 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop  - Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5-cdh5.2.0
  3212 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
  3213 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
  3213 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool  - delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
  3224 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.ConnFactory  - $SQOOP_CONF_DIR has not been set in the environment. Cannot check for additional configuration.
  3280 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.oracle.OraOopManagerFactory  - Data Connector for Oracle and Hadoop is disabled.
  3293 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Using default fetchSize of 1000
  3297 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool  - Beginning code generation
  3951 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager  - Time zone has been set to GMT
  4023 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager  - Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM PT_PRELIM_FINDING_V t WHERE 1=0
  4068 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
  5925 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager  - Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-nobody/compile/0dab11f6545d8ef69d6dd0f6b9041a50/PT_PRELIM_FINDING_CYTOGEN_V.jar
  5937 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase  - Beginning import of PT_PRELIM_FINDING_V
  5962 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager  - Time zone has been set to GMT
  5981 [main] WARN  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.JobBase  - SQOOP_HOME is unset. May not be able to find all job dependencies.
  6769 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat  - Using read commited transaction isolation
  Heart beat
  Heart beat
  Heart beat
  Heart beat
  Heart beat 
  Heart beat
```

Comment: It looks like your database is not responding. Maybe you need to increase parallelization there. If you reach out to the user@sqoop.apache.org mailing list, the community might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @abeaamase.

I asked our DBA to increase oracle database max process to 750 and max session pool to around 1.5 times process size i.e 1125.
This has solved the issue. This has nothing to do with yarn memory.Unfortunately in sqoop2 this exception is not handled.
Please feel free to add more answers,if you feel this explanation is not appropriate.